# Which books will give u deep concept/understanding in real analysis Apostol calculus Vol-1 or Baby Rudin?

Tags: reference-request, soft-question, self-learning

I have some confusion about book in learning real analysis

Which books will give u deep concept/understanding  in real analysis   Apostol calculus Vol$-1$  or Baby Rudin ?

**My thinking** : I think both books  are same  but Apostol vol$-1$ have many problem/exercise as compared to Baby Rudin

Baby Rudin look thinner than Apostol calculas Vol$-1$

In mathematics the more problem u solved the more u learn

So i think Apostol will be more better  because it contains lots of problem

But I did n't touch the Apostol book till now  .But I have baby Rudin hard  copy

Comment: If you're looking for real analysis, I think Apostol wrote a book called Mathematical Analysis (or something like that). I have not read any of his books, but I think that's his real analysis book. His Calculus volumes presumably won't teach you real analysis with the same rigor. Personally I am reading the three volume series Analysis by Amann and Escher. As far as I know this is the most general and mature perspective on analysis available. I am happy with it so far.

Comment: okkss @Novice i thinks  both are same

Comment: **CAVEAT**: I have a copy of "baby" Rudin but only remember reading parts of Apostol's calculus books years ago. **MY RESPONSE**: How much time do you have? I ask because "baby" Rudin yields intuition through hard work. Apostol's calculus books require less intensity but also yield less experience. And if I recall correctly, Apostol's calculus books do not incorporate differential forms, while more recent editions of baby Rudin do use them.

Comment: @Novice  i mean Mathematical analysis and Apostol vol-1   coz  content are almost same   except measure theory

Comment: okk that mean   Baby Rudin will be more better  for learning Real analysis @JoeMack

Comment: You must read and do problems **longer** in baby Rudin to gain **true** understanding, but your understanding will be deeper. Don't commit yourself to just one book. A good student might find that a good book just does not resonate. That student should seek another good book but be willing to return to the first book after getting the first level of intuition.

Comment: @Novice Hi there -- thanks very much for this helpful comment. I am interested in self-studying Amann-Escher but am worried about the lack of solution manual (for both unfortunately). If you had any opinions or suggestions, I would greatly appreciate it. The alternative would be Zorich which, it seems, doesn't have a manual either! Thanks for your time.

Comment: @EE18 Hi, I have been sidetracked with other things so I haven't done much other than the first chapter of A&E. Regarding the lack of a solution manual, I'm not sure what to say. Solutions to exercises are only part of developing an understanding of the material. I am not sure this is enough of a drawback to A&E to make me use a different textbook. I would probably consider glancing at some other textbooks as well (e.g. Tao) and using online communities (such as this one) to help with solutions. Good luck.

Comment: Touche. Thanks very much for the nice note and all the best to you too!